# Как сделать прогресс бар на Python?

Tags: python

как сделать вот такое на Python + Linux?
[image: #ПомогитеПоPython!]

Comment: Нужен именно псевдографический интерфейс?

Comment: приведённая картинка явно нарисована программой *whiptail*. если искать строку «python+whiptal», то первая ссылка: https://pypi.org/project/whiptail/

Comment: Да.Такой нужен,нравиться такой потому что я делаю свою ОС На Python